# Setting repositories and providers

Tags: domain-driven-design, castle-windsor

Im having a little bit of a problem trying to figure out how to do the following. My apologies if thhe following seems idiotic, just new to Castle.Windsor.

Right, In my application repositories should point to diferent dbs. They all share a abstract class (Db methods abstraction) but there is no correlation between them.
So I have something like this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
   private readonly IUserRepository _repository;
   public UserService(IUserRepository repository) { _repository = repository; }
   ...
}

public class UserRepository : Mongo, IUserRepository
{
  public UserRepository(DatabaseHosts.Users UsersHost) : base(UsersHost) { }
  ...
}
```

All configuration settings are strongly typed and so far I am calling a Installer for the Settings Service before i call Install on the rest.

My question would be: Do i have to register services and Respositories or there is something im missing?

I think, We could allow access to the DbHost property from the Service, but i rather like not.
 We also have providers to external systems which might need some sort of initialization.

So far i have soemthing like this:

```
public class ServicesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
       container.Register(Component.For<IUserService>()
                .ImplementedBy<IUserService>()
                .LifeStyle.Singleton);
   }
}
```

Ta

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
       container.Register(Component.For<IUserService>()
                .ImplementedBy<UserService>()
                .LifeStyle.Singleton);
   }
```

you have to register the concrete service "UserService" to the interface in order to allow the container to determine which concrete to resolve.

Comment: That is what i have so far, the question is DO i register my repositories in the installer or I pass the DbHost property from the Service down to the repository. Have in mind i dont use Context or UnitOfWork or similar. so in essence i need to initilize the repository with the proper string.

Comment: It is preferable to register it and use DI to make it testable instead of passing concrete context from the service.